# error with simple ggplot2 line plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to make a simple line plot but I get the following error:

> geom_path: Each group consist of only one observation. Do you need to
>   adjust the group aesthetic?

I want status.std on the y-axis, effort on the x-axis, with status_measure distinguishing the two separate lines.

Below is my data and the code I'm executing:

```
df.effort <- structure(list(effort = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L), .Label = c("never", "not very hard", "hard enough", "very hard"
), class = "factor"), status.std = structure(c(-0.0234448237301297, 
0.0568346993679614, 0.0780165665285588, -0.0380394621882508, 
-0.135535917573711, 0.0128879641418037, 0.0806307867881565, -0.0104818763687783
), .Names = c("never", "not very hard", "hard enough", "very hard", 
"never", "not very hard", "hard enough", "very hard")), status_measure = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("avrank.zmgs", "acent09l.zmgs"
), class = "factor")), .Names = c("effort", "status.std", "status_measure"
), row.names = c(NA, 8L), class = "data.frame")

ggplot(data=df.effort,
       aes(x=effort), y=status.std, colour=status_measure)) +   geom_line()
```

Many thanks for any help.  I regret that this question seems unlikely to be instructive to others.  If there is a title edit or something that would make it more general that would be fantastic.

Comment: Follow the instructions in the error message: add `group=status_measure` to your `aes()` call. (Also, you messed up the parentheses in your code, so as written, it won't run at all.)

Comment: Also `y` is defined outside of `aes()` it needs to be defined inside. I think all you need to do is remove the `)` at the end of effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Syntax error. Need to move the paren so that aes(...) gets both the x and y arguments (but *not* the colour argument, because simply moving to the end generates the error you posted.)

```
ggplot(data=df.effort,
       aes(x=effort, y=status.std), colour=status_measure) +   geom_line()
```

Which succeeds but fails to color anything. And how could a color be picked for the lines anyway? I think the colors would adhere to the points, so try this:

```
ggplot(data=df.effort,  aes(x=effort, y=status.std))+ 
   geom_line()+ 
   geom_point(data=df.effort, 
       aes(x=effort, y=status.std, colour=status_measure))
```

Or maybe you do want what joran posted:

```
ggplot(data=df.effort,
   aes(x=effort, y=status.std, colour=status_measure, group=status_measure)) +
   geom_line()
```

(I thought you were trying to use geom_line to link measurements within category of effort with color distinguishing between status measures.)

Comment: Thanks to you and the others, +1 for all